# Is my palindromic sum code in the right direction? How do I calculate cycle length?

Tags: python

I have an assignment to create a program that asks for starting and ending number in a range that prints out the number that has the longest cycle length. I'm really new to programming and am not sure if I am doing this correctly. I am not sure if my program is selecting the number with the longest cycle length. How would I ask the program to provide the cycle length? I have two definitions (is_palindromic, and rev_num) that were given to me by my professor that I have to have in my assignment.

```
# determines if a number is palindromic
def is_palindromic (n):
    return (n == rev_num(n))

# reverses a number
def rev_num (n):
    rev_n = 0
    while (n > 0):
        rev_n = rev_n * 10 + (n % 10)
        n = n // 10
    return (rev_n)

def main():
    start = eval (input ("Enter starting number: "))
    end = eval (input ("Enter ending number: "))
    total = 0
    cycle_length = 0
    while (start <= end):

        if (is_palindromic((start))):
            total += start
        start = start + 1
        cycle_length += 1
    print (total)
    print (cycle_length)

main()
```

Comment: What's a cycle length?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mitra/csSpring2016/cs303/assgn/assgn4.html) what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found with some duck-ducking:

> If any number is reversed and added to itself, and the process repeated long enough, a palindromic number will result most of the time. A palindromic number is one that reads the same forward and backward.
>
> We will define cycle length in this scenario as the number of steps required to achieve a palindromic number. A step is defined to be the addition of the reverse of a number to itself.
>
> The cycle length of all palindromic numbers is zero. Since all single digits numbers are palindromic, their cycle length is zero.
>
> If the starting number is 57 then the number of steps taken to reach a palindromic number is 2.
>
> 57
>
> 132  [57 + 75 = 132]
>
> 363  [132 + 231 = 363]

Here are some hints to get you going:

1. You shouldn't update `start`, because you are likely to want to print the starting and ending numbers somewhere at the end of the program. Don't lose information if you can avoid it. Just create another variable.
2. The `range()` function exists to handle iterating over a range of numbers. Just beware that it **does not** include the ending member, so you will have to do `range(start, end+1)`.
3. The *cycle length* is a characteristic of the individual number you are considering. So you won't be incrementing it as part of your outermost loop.
4. However, you do need to track the *longest* cycle length. So you should probably keep a `max_key, max_value` pair that you can test and update each time. (If current_value > max_value, set max_key = current_key, max_value = current_value)
5. If I were you, I would include a "sanity check" in your cycle-length computations, since the assignment warns that some cycles appear to be infinite. Just pick a number, like 100, and if the computed cycle length goes above that, stop computing (and maybe print a warning message).
6. Computing the cycle length would be a good function, if you know about writing functions.